# Ehcache -- Expiring on certain time

Tags: java, ehcache

When using ehcache, is there a way to expire cache on certain time of the day?

Thanks,

Lawardy

Answer (score 2):

There is no such functionality out-of-the-box. You need an external solution like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org), also from [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/products) umbrella.

In fact, even normal `timeToLive` parameter does not remove element in question after this time elapses, because this would required additional thread. Instead the item is removed when new one is to be added which takes its place.